# How to delegate implementation to a property in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin enables me to implement an interface by delegating to a primary constructor argument like so:

```
class Foo(xs : ArrayList<Int>) : List<Int> by xs { }
```

But this exhibits the backing implementer to the user. Delegating to an anonymous also seems to be ok:

```
class Foo() : List<Int> by ArrayList<Int>() { }
```

This hides the implementation details, but we loose access to features not provided by the interface, which in this case is mutability.

I would therefore like to delegate the implementation to a property that is not in the primary constructor. What I would like to have is similar to

```
class Foo() : List<Int> by xs {
    val xs : List<Int> = ArrayList<Int>()
}
```

which doesn't compile.

Is it possible to have a property defined explicitly in the class body and still be able to delegate implementation to it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not currently possible. The expression in the `by`-clause is computed only once before the construction of the class, so you cannot reference symbols of that class.

There is a [request in the issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-83) to allow this, although it's almost definitely not going to be supported in Kotlin 1.0.

One funny workaround that *sometimes* works is to make the property which you want to be a delegate, a constructor parameter with the default value instead. That way it'll be accessible both in the `by`-clause and in the class body:

```
class Foo(val xs: List<Int> = ArrayList<Int>()) : List<Int> by xs {
    fun bar() {
        println(xs)
    }
}
```

Keep in mind though that `xs` in `by xs` is still calculated only once here, so even if `xs` is a `var` property, only the default value provided in the constructor will be used. It's not a universal solution, but sometimes it can help.

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on the answer of Alexander Udalov, I came up with a solution using a private base class

```
private open class FooBase(protected val xs : MutableList<Int>) : List<Int> by xs { }

class Foo() : FooBase(ArrayList()) {
    fun bar() {
        xs.add(5)
    }
}
```

Now I can have access to the property backing my interface implementation but am not restricted to operations provided by that interface while still hiding the actual implementation from the user.

**Note:** Although it works, I get the following warning from IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE which arises from `EXPOSED_SUPER_CLASS` inspection: *Deprecated: subclass effective visibility 'public' should be the same or less permissive than its superclass effective visibility 'private'*. I'm not quite sure what the *deprecated* part here means – whether the warning will be removed in the future or this won't compile at some point. Anyway, we don't really have to use a `private open` class, `abstract` or simply `open` will do, because even if the user is allowed to create an instance of `FooBase`, there is not much he can do with it.

### Update:

There is actualy a simple and compact solution that does not use any suspicious behaviour:

```
class Foo private constructor(private val xs: ArrayList<Int>) : List<Int> by xs {
    constructor() : this(ArrayList<Int>()) { }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about why this deprecation happened. I receive the same in cases like this. What is the motivation?